# How to convert an xml element object into a string with a namespace prefix in Python?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml

I have a following code:

```
from lxml.etree import tostring, Element, SubElement
element = Element('mytag')
sub_element = SubElement(element, 'mysubtag')
print(tostring(element, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))
```

that outputs:

```
<mytag>
  <mysubtag/>
</mytag>
```

In which way should I modify it to add a namespace prefix to each tag to have such result:

```
<mynspref:mytag>
  <mynspref:mysubtag/>
</mynspref:mytag>
```

Comment: dexml module  might also help

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/dexml/api/dexml.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `register_namespace()` to associate the prefix with a namespace URI and use that URI when creating elements.

```
from lxml import etree

NS = "http://www.example.com"
etree.register_namespace("mynspref", NS)

element = etree.Element('{%s}mytag' % NS)
sub_element = etree.SubElement(element, '{%s}mysubtag' % NS)

print(etree.tostring(element, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))
```

Result:

```
<mynspref:mytag xmlns:mynspref="http://www.example.com">
  <mynspref:mysubtag/>
</mynspref:mytag>
```