# How to insert an attribute with the right namespace prefix using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

Is there a way, using [lxml](https://lxml.de/), to insert XML attributes with the right namespace?

For instance, I want to use [XLink](https://www.w3.org/TR/xlink11/) to insert links in a XML document. All I need to do is to insert `{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}href` attributes in some elements. I would like to use `xlink` prefix, but lxml generates prefixes like "ns0", "ns1"…

Here is what I tried:

```py
from lxml import etree

#: Name (and namespace) of the *href* attribute use to insert links.
HREF_ATTR = etree.QName("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href").text

content = """\
<body>
<p>Link to <span>StackOverflow</span></p>
<p>Link to <span>Google</span></p>
</body>
"""

targets = ["https://stackoverflow.com", "https://www.google.fr"]
body_elem = etree.XML(content)
for span_elem, target in zip(body_elem.iter("span"), targets):
    span_elem.attrib[HREF_ATTR] = target

etree.dump(body_elem)
```

The dump looks like this:

```xml
<body>
<p>link to <span xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                 ns0:href="https://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</span></p>
<p>link to <span xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                 ns1:href="https://www.google.fr">google</span></p>
</body>
```

I found a way to factorize the namespaces by inserting and deleting an attribute in the root element, like this:

```py
# trick to declare the XLink namespace globally (only one time).
body_elem = etree.XML(content)
body_elem.attrib[HREF_ATTR] = ""
del body_elem.attrib[HREF_ATTR]

targets = ["https://stackoverflow.com", "https://www.google.fr"]
for span_elem, target in zip(body_elem.iter("span"), targets):
    span_elem.attrib[HREF_ATTR] = target

etree.dump(body_elem)
```

It's ugly, but it works and I only need to do it one time. I get:

```xml
<body xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<p>Link to <span ns0:href="https://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</span></p>
<p>Link to <span ns0:href="https://www.google.fr">Google</span></p>
</body>
```

But the problem remains: how can I turn this "ns0" prefix into "xlink"?

Comment: It should work if you use `register_namespace()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43907396/407651

Answer (score 2):

Using [`register_namespace`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#register_namespace) as suggested by @mzjn:

```py
etree.register_namespace("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")

# trick to declare the XLink namespace globally (only one time).
body_elem = etree.XML(content)
body_elem.attrib[HREF_ATTR] = ""
del body_elem.attrib[HREF_ATTR]

targets = ["https://stackoverflow.com", "https://www.google.fr"]
for span_elem, target in zip(body_elem.iter("span"), targets):
    span_elem.attrib[HREF_ATTR] = target

etree.dump(body_elem)
```

The result is what I expected:

```xml
<body xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<p>Link to <span xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</span></p>
<p>Link to <span xlink:href="https://www.google.fr">Google</span></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Side note: instead of creating and deleting the `HREF_ATTR` on `body` to declare the namespace globally, you can use [`cleanup_namespaces()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#cleanup_namespaces). Example: `etree.cleanup_namespaces(body_elem, top_nsmap={"xlink": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"})`